# jekyll: show title and date in opened blog post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

i have an blog index page with a list of blog posts and excerpts.
once i click on the "read more" link, the full blog post is opened but lacks of its title and date of creation.

the blog index is structured like so:

```
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
    <div class="entry">

        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>

            <span class="date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ post.date | date: "%m-%d-%Y"}}</span>

        {{ post.excerpt }}
        <a class="more-link" href="{{ post.url }}">continue reading <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

i've tried throwing `{{ post.title }}` and the date in blog posts, both in the front matter or inline in the article, but it just shows up empty.

how can i show the title in my opened blog post?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit how your blog posts are displayed you have to edit the template file in the `_layouts` folder. By default Jekyll uses `post.html` as a template for blog posts. Make sure that you have `{{ page.title }}` in the used layout file and regenerate your site. Now the blog title will appear on all of your individual post pages, please note that it won't appear if the post title is not specified in the front matter of the post.

Comment: as of now, the post title in blog/index.html appears only in the excerpts page without using {{post.title}} anywhere on the site, i guess it automatically takes it from the filename.md - i did as you said: i've put {{ post.title }} in the _layout structure of the blogpost and nothing happens, just an empty tag. any other variables like site.url etc. don't work for me. what can it be?

Comment: There are a lot of things that could cause it, to make it easier for people to help you I can suggest uploading it to github and sharing a link. This way the problem can be tracked easily.

Comment: it's on github if you want to have a look: https://github.com/vlrprbttst/valeriopierbattista.com-2016/ thanks so much im going crazy with this :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, you have to use {{ page.title }} NOT {{ post.title }} and you will see the name of your blog post on your blog page, enjoy

Comment: I didn't try it but you can try `{{ page.date }}` if it returns an entry string you'll have to add a front matter to your blog posts and add a date value in there so Jekyll could get it from the front matter